# storing values with keys then searching the smartest way, ALGORITHMS

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I've got a stream with > 20 millions of values which come with their corresponding key (> 10 millions). The keys are linked to one or more values (max 50000), example:

```
... (key1, val1), (key2,val2), (key1, val3), (key2, val4), (key1, val6), (key3,val5)...
```

I store this stream as follows:

key1 : val1, val3, val6

key2 : val2, val4

key3 : val5

Each time I receive a new value in the stream, I first check if this value appears in the list of its corresponding key:

- If it's not, i add the value at the end of the list.
- If the value is already in the list at the last place, then I do
  nothing.
- Finally, if the value is already in the list, but not at the last
  place, i launch a flag.

My question is: what's the more efficient data structure or tools to perform this process (I want to launch the flag the faster possible). I thought of a hash table associated with linked list (as I give in the example), but checking all the linked list each time I add a value does not sound right. Recall that I do need this notion of LAST value.

Thank you

Comment: Your current algorithm is not clear.  Please add an example showing how you would handle one (or more) or the three use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking if the new value is in the list is not optimal - it takes `O(n)` time to check.

You can use a hashtable instead. You can store the last value separately and update it on insert.

So you have a hashtable, where the values are pairs. Each pair consists of a hashtable (used as a set) and an element (the last element in the set).

Your example looks like this:

```
(key1 -> (val6, (val1->1, val3->1, val6->1))
(key2 -> (val4, (val2->1, val4->1)
(key3 -> (val5, (val5->1))
```

You can optimize the cases when the set only contains one element, by not storing the last value explicitly.

Comment: Thats sounds great, thank you a lot. I wait a bit to see if another idea comes.